# C++ bind allowing arbitrary function signature conversions?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, currying

I know the title is not very good but I have no idea what should be the proper title. I will edit the title if a better one is suggested.

Now, I have a class that can register callbacks (to call them when events happen).
The API is supposed to be pretty simple:

```
obj.register_callback(my_callback)
```

`my_callback` has a pretty simple signature: `void my_callback(string s1, string s2)`.

However `obj.register_callback` asks for an argument of type `std::function<void(const char* s1, const string& s2, long long i1, long long i2, long long i3)>` because it has alot of information to pass to the callback.

I only need the first 2 strings, I have no use for the last 3 ints.

If I try to pass `my_callback` directly to `register_callback` I get the expected

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void (string, string)" to
"function<void (const char *, const string &, long long, long long, long long)>"
```

One way would be to simply modify the signature of `my_callback` to include 3 more useless arguments, however this is pretty ugly.

I have seen some examples of the callback function being "processed" in the following way:

```
auto new_callback = bind(my_callback, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2));
obj.register_callback(new_callback);
```

I have some knowledge of currying so the concept of what `bind` does is familiar, so looking at it:

```
auto new_callback  = bind(my_callback, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
```

From what I can gather about `std::bind` and `placeholders`, in the above case `bind` will output a function that:

- takes 2 arguments
- will call `my_callback`
- the 1st argument of `new_callback` will be passed as the 1st argument of `my_callback`
- the 2nd argument of `new_callback` will be passed as the 2nd argument of `my_callback`

Problem is that `obj.register_callback(new_callback);` seems to work. I am confused as to why.
What exactly does `bind` do that allows this to work even if the signatures are clearly different?

The only thing I can sort of see is that the output function of `bind` takes any number of arguments, but will only really use the ones that are referenced via `placeholders::_X` by passing them to the curried function. Is this right? Or what exactly happens that allows this to work?

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I can sort of see is that the output function of `bind` takes any number of arguments, but will only really use the ones that are referenced via `placeholders::_X` by passing them to the curried function. Is this right? Or what exactly happens that allows this to work?

That's correct. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

> If the stored argument arg is of type T, for which std::is_placeholder::value != 0 (meaning, a placeholder such as std::placeholders::_1, _2, _3, ... was used as the argument to the initial call to bind), then the argument indicated by the placeholder (u1 for _1, u2 for _2, etc) is passed to the invokable object: the argument vn in the std::invoke call above is std::forward(uj) and the corresponding type Vn in the same call is Uj&&.

> Otherwise, the ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument: the argument vn in the std::invoke call above is simply arg and the corresponding type Vn is T cv &, where cv is the same cv-qualification as that of g.

Most likely bound object's `operator()` utilizes variadic template/parameter pack under the hood, see here: https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/functional.html#372

Comment: One could also use a lambda: `obj.register_callback([](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, ...) { my_callback(s1, s2); });`

Comment: I dont understand how this works. Sure - the _unspecified_ type returned by `std::bind` is invokable - it has a complex `operator()`. But that seems to not be happening here. In @OPs example is somehow being converted to a std::function in this line: `obj.register_callback(new_callback);` but I cant see how.

Comment: @MikeVine see [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8438Yb1EP). It uses a generic lambda, but the underlying logic is exactly the same.

Comment: I dont understand what thats got to do with `std::bind`. I understand how it _could_ be implemented but from what I can see in the standard, the return value from `std::bind` is only invokable which doesn't mean it could be converted to other types.

Comment: This is assuming that `register_callback` takes a `std::function` as stated by op.

Comment: @MikeVine `template <typename ...Args> operator()(Args...args)` can be converted (or rather I should say: resolved at compile time) to `std::function<void(string, string, long, long)>` whereas `void(string, string)` can not. Unless I'm missing yet another point of your question.

Comment: OK I think I've found what I was missing. I was too busy looking at what its possible to do with the unspecified return type of `std::bind`. I should've been looking at the constructors for `std::function`. `std::function` can be constructed with anything which is callable - not just functions/other std::functions/lambdas, but _anything invokable_ which is why this works.